# Создание рандомной генерации terrain unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, terrain

Я написал скрипт и при запуске часть terrain не заполнена вот скрипт

```
{
    private readonly int width = 200;
    private readonly int height = 200;
    public static int CoreHeight = 100;
    private readonly float scale = 4f;
    private float offsetX = 100f;
    private float offsetY = 100f;
    private void Start()
    {
        CoreHeight = height;
        offsetY = Random.Range(50, offsetY);
        offsetX = Random.Range(50, offsetX);
        Terrain terrain = GetComponent<Terrain>();
        terrain.terrainData = GenerateTerrain(terrain.terrainData);
    }

    private TerrainData GenerateTerrain(TerrainData terrainData)
    {
        terrainData.heightmapResolution = width;
        terrainData.size = new Vector3(width, scale, height);
        float[,] heights = GenerateHeights();
        terrainData.SetHeights(0, 0, heights);
        return terrainData;
    }

    private float[,] GenerateHeights()
    {
        float[,] heights = new float[width, height];
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            {
                heights[x, y] = CalculateHeight(x, y);
            }
        }
        return heights;
    }

    private float CalculateHeight(int x, int y)
    {
        offsetX = Random.Range(10, offsetY);
        offsetY = Random.Range(10, offsetX);
        float xCoord = (float)x / width * 4 + offsetX;
        float yCoord = (float)y / height * 4 + offsetY;
        return Mathf.PerlinNoise(xCoord, yCoord);
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что такое `scale`? И у вас две разных сущности называются `height`. Вы уж определитесь - вы `heights` генерите, или у вас `height` задана так же как `width`? Не говоря уж о том, что в `GenerateHeights` у вас в цикле сущности местами перепутаны. Для квадрата это не страшно, а если будет не квадрат? Короче. Сначала определитесь, где у вас что - где ширина, где высота, а где скажем длина `length`. Без наведения порядка в терминах и сущностях разбирать код, где все термины перепутаны, без толку. Разберитесь с терминами, может тогда и с кодом всё понятно станет.

Comment: Спасибо что написали про то что я перепутал значения.